# Bootstrap Navbar not Collapsing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The Problem: Navbar STARTS as open. On collapse, the links still show, only the background collapses. I've made sure I'm using transitions and I've got all the bootstrap javascript in there, the bootstrap css and some of my own styling on top, but nothing that I think would affect the navbar.

[What it looks like default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1REJ3.png)

[What it looks likes closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo8dB.jpg)

My Code:

```
<body>
<!--Navbar -->
<div class="contactUs">
    <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span>&nbsp;00000000
    </p>
</div>
<!-- logo -->

<!-- end logo -->
<!-- Static navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand main-logo pull-left" href="index.html">SX Storage Essex Benfleet</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#selfStorage">Self Storage</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#businessStorage">Business Storage</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Prices</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Packaging </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End navbar -->
```

Comment: The code you pasted above doesn't have any problem. The problem might be with the extra CSS you have written.

Comment: Your HTML seems to work fine in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/117918). Maybe you have accidentally overwritten some CSS rules?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, something was missing from bootstrap css. I just included the CDN. Not sure how that happened, I don't touch the bootstrap css - I'm going to put it down to zombie-mode late night keyboard mashing.